# write pic in wma file with mutagen

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a tag editor for multiple types of files, for which I am using the mutagen library, but I can not find any information on how to place albumart in the wma files (ASF).

Please, if anyone has any information about it, it would be very useful.